# How to clearInterval when component is unmounted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, clearinterval

I have this simplified code below. When the user clicks on CLICK ME it will start a 5 second interval that after that will doSomethingImportant(). It works well, except on the case someone clicks on another component (Toolbar, footer) that brings you to a different component. In that case, the interval will keep executing all the time. How can I prevent that from happening? So that when AnswerScreen is unmounted, the interval is cleared? The "trick" below doesn't work.

```
const AnswerScreen = (props) => {

    const [timeout, setTimeout] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {        
      return () => { clearInterval(timeout) }
    }, []);
    
    const itemClickHandler = (index, value) => {
      setTimeout(setInterval(() => {
        props.doSomethingImportant();
        return () => { clearInterval(timeout) }
      }, 5000));    
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={() => itemClickHandler(3, 4)}>CLICK ME</div>
    );
}
    
export default connect(null, null)(AnswerScreen);
```

Comment: `setInterval` returns an ID which you use to clear. Not React related. But either way just do this, don't try to roll your own https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: @AndyRay I am not trying to create my own ID, just storing the one returned by setInterval() as state variable "timeout" so that I can use it in clearInterval(). But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## clearTimeout( id )

> With **`setTimeout`** use `clearTimeout`

> With **`setInterval`** use `clearInterval`

To clear the timeout when routing to another component

```
useEffect(()=>{
 return () => clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
},[])
```

To clear previous timeout when user click the button 2 or more times

```
const AnswerScreen = (props) => {
    const timeoutRef = useRef(null);
    
      const itemClickHandler = (index, value) => {
          if(timeoutRef.current) clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
          timeoutRef.current=setTimeout(setInterval(() => {
             //do what ever you want
             props.doSomethingImportant();
          }, 5000));   
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={() => itemClickHandler(3, 4)}>CLICK ME</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You forgot the return in your `useEffect` callback.  .